# NPM run error: AssignProcessToJobObject: (6) The handle is invalid

Tags: npm, angular14, npm-run

My angular app is built using Angular 14, nestjs 8 and nrwl 14. When I am trying to build the application, it builds successfully with no error but when I am trying to run the application, it is throwing below error. Kindly help on this.

Command to run the application

```
nx run ui-app:serve:development --port=4200 --ssl=true --o=true
```

Build generated successfully:

[image]

Error:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on https://localhost:4200/ **

AssignProcessToJobObject: (6) The handle is invalid.

 ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

 >  NX   Running target "ui-app:serve" failed

   Failed tasks:

   - ui-app:serve:development

   Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ui-app@0.0.0 start:ui-app: `node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve ui-app --port 4200 --ssl true -o`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ui-app@0.0.0 start:ui-app script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Verbose Error

```
npm verb lifecycle ui-app@0.0.0~start:ui-app: CWD: C:\Users\Rahul\WorkSpace\Project\ui-app
npm info lifecycle ui-app@0.0.0~start:ui-app: Failed to exec start:ui-app script
npm verb stack Error: ui-app@0.0.0 start:ui-app: `node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve ui-app --port 4200 --ssl true -o`
npm verb stack Exit status 1
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
npm verb pkgid ui-app@0.0.0
npm verb cwd C:\Users\Rahul\WorkSpace\Project\ui-app
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm verb argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start:ui-app" "--verbose"
npm verb node v14.21.1
npm verb npm  v6.14.17
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ui-app@0.0.0 start:ui-app: `node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve ui-app --port 4200 --ssl true -o`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ui-app@0.0.0 start:ui-app script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 220039ms
```

Comment: Like the output suggests, please run the command with the `--verbose` flag added and post any relevant logs

Comment: Whats the output when you run with --verbose flag? Pls post here

Comment: Getting same error which is pasted. I edited the question. Please see there. Thanks.

Comment: Still looking for a solution, anybody have it, kindly post here.